# variable is not accessible in angular.forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, angularjs

I have a service

```
app.service('myService', function() {
    this.list = [];
    this.execute = function() {
        //this.list is reachable here
        angular.forEach(AnArrayHere, function(val, key) {
           //this.list is not reachable here
        });
    }
}
```

even in controller its accessible

```
function Ctrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.list = myService.list;
}
```

Can someone explain me why "this.list" is not reachable within the angular.foreach and how can I access to "this.list" ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The last parameter in the `angular.forEach` (See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach) function is the context for `this`. So you'll want something like this:

```
app.service('myService', function() {

    this.list = [];

    this.execute = function() {

        //this.list is reachable here

        angular.forEach(AnArrayHere, function(val, key) {
           //access this.list
        }, this);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, angular docs had nothing about how to inject scope variable into the loop.

Answer (score 6):

The reason `this.list` is not accessible in the foreach is because the context for that function call has changed. It works inside the `execute` method as that method is part of the same context as list.

Due to all the closures I would assign the `this` context to another variable that you can then call later on. Something like this:

```
app.service('myService', function() {

    var self = this;
    self.list = [];

    self.execute = function() {
        //this.list and self.list are reachable here
        angular.forEach(AnArrayHere, function(val, key) {
           //self.this == this.list
        });
    }
}
```

This is a slightly more general solution than passing the context as part of the foreach method call and would work in other closure related situations.