# concat and push overrides what has been previously added to the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does this replace instead of adding onto the object?

I have also tried using `this.push()` instead of `.concat()` but exactly the same thing happens, it overrides whats been previously added the object.

```
$scope.checkMatchinAnswer = function (required, ans, input) {
    $scope.correctAnswers = [];

    angular.forEach(required, function (value) {
        if (angular.equals(value.answer, ans) && angular.equals(value.id, qid)) {
            $scope.correctAnswers = $scope.correctAnswers.concat([{
                id: qid,
                answer: value.answer
            }]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.correctAnswers.push.apply($scope.correctAnswers, [{...}])`?

Comment: What does `.apply()` do differently?

Comment: `concat` creates a new array, `push.apply` will mutate the original object.

Comment: please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013016/variable-is-not-accessible-in-angular-foreach. I believe you need to specify which context to use within the foreach loop.

Comment: I sort of still need it to create a new object for each `.push()` or `.concat()`, as I do an `angular.equals()` to compare this with another object that I cannot really adjust as its a third party JSON file.

Comment: @Cédric that approach would not work as I have the conditional stuff in the `angular.foreach()` which then finds the "correct answer" and adds it to the object.

Comment: @Cédric if you think this is still possible, please feel free to post an answer :)

Comment: @MichaelWilson2013  please check the jsfiddle and let me know if this answers your question: http://jsfiddle.net/cseignc/n5r7rLa6/3/  (There was no reference to qid in your original post so I had to make some minor alterations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was creating a new scope everytime I called:

```
$scope.correctAnswers = [];
```

I needed to create the scope outside of the function and pass through whats been previously added:

```
    $scope.checkMatchinAnswer = function(required, ans, input) {

       if(!input){ 
           $scope.correctAnswers = [];
       }

        angular.forEach(required, function (value) {
               console.log(angular.equals(value.answer, ans), angular.equals(value.id, qid));
             if(angular.equals(value.answer, ans) != false && angular.equals(value.id, qid) != false){
                    this.push({ id: qid, answer: value.answer });
             }
        }, $scope.correctAnswers);
        return $scope.correctAnswers;
    }
```

then outside I would use this conditional:

```
if($scope.correctAnswers != []) {
    $scope.checkMatchinAnswer(content.required, ans, $scope.correctAnswers);
} else {
    $scope.correctAnswers = $scope.checkMatchinAnswer(content.required, ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making this more complicated than it is.

Doing the following sets a new value, which is not what you want.

```
$scope.correctAnswers =
```

It appears you just want to push new vlaues so do this:

```
$scope.correctAnswers.push({
    id: qid,
    answer: value.answer
})
```